# Openjpa slice executeUpdate for createNativeQuery

Tags: java, openjpa, slice

Is it possible to use executeUpdate for createNativeQuery on openjpa slice?
We tried something like this but that doesn’t update any record. We are using 
MySQL database. Log shows that updates go to both slices and are immediately rollbacked. Everything works fine without slice.

```
String updateQueryString = "update address set name = ?1 ";
 Query query = JPA.em().createNativeQuery(updateQueryString)
.setHint("openjpa.hint.slice.Target", “One”)
                .setParameter(1, "adr1");
query.executeUpdate();
```

Our persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"             
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"  version="2.0">

   <persistence-unit name="slice">
        <provider>
             org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
        </provider>
        <class>controllers.Address</class>
        <class>controllers.User</class>
        <class>models.Account</class>
        <class>controllers.CostCenter</class>
        <properties>
          <property name="openjpa.BrokerFactory" value="slice"/>
          <property name="openjpa.slice.Names" value="One, Two"/>
           <property name="openjpa.slice.Master" value="One"/>
          <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="*****"/>
          <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="******"/>
          <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName"      
value="org.apache.openjpa.slice.jdbc"/>
          <property name="openjpa.slice.DistributionPolicy" 
value="sharding.RublysDistributionPolicy"/>
          <property name="openjpa.slice.QueryTargetPolicy " 
value="sharding.RublysQueryTargetPolicy"/>
          <property name="openjpa.slice.FinderTargetPolicy" 
value="sharding.RublysTargetPolicy" />
          <property name="openjpa.slice.ReplicatedTypes"
value="models.Account,controllers.CostCenter"/>
          <property name="openjpa.slice.One.ConnectionURL" 
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/slice1"/>
          <property name="openjpa.slice.One.ConnectionDriverName"
value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
          <property name="openjpa.slice.Two.ConnectionURL" 
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asrtest2"/>
          <property name="openjpa.slice.Two.ConnectionDriverName" 
value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
          <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" 
value="false"/>
         <property name="openjpa.Log" 
value="SQL=TRACE, Runtime=TRACE, DefaultLevel=TRACE ,Tool=TRACE"/>
        <property name="openjpa.Multithreaded"   value="true"/>
       <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="refresh"/>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.MappingDefaults" value="DefaultMissingInfo=true"/>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="mysql"/>
      <property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="false"/>
      <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="false"/>
      <property name="openjpa.QueryCompilationCache" value="false"/>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.QuerySQLCache" value="false"/>
          <property name="openjpa.jdbc.FinderCache" value="false"/>
          <property name="openjpa.DetachState" value="loaded(DetachedStateField=false)"/>
          <property name="openjpa.slice.ThreadingPolicy"     value="fixed"/>
   </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```